# Yii2 php init command

Tags: yii2

What does `php init` command actually do?

When I run this command in cmd after creating my project using this command: `composer create-project --prefer-dist yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced advanced`

I see many files generated in different locations like common, backend, frontend.

```
 `some@user:/var/www/html/yiiapp$ php init
  Yii Application Initialization Tool v1.0

  Which environment do you want the application to be initialized in?

[0] Development
 [1] Production

Your choice [0-1, or "q" to quit] 0

Initialize the application under 'Development' environment? [yes|no] yes

Start initialization ...

  exist common/config/main-local.php
        ...overwrite? [Yes|No|All|Quit] All
overwrite common/config/main-local.php
unchanged common/config/params-local.php
unchanged yii
overwrite backend/config/main-local.php
unchanged backend/config/params-local.php
unchanged backend/web/index-test.php
unchanged backend/web/index.php
unchanged api/web/index-test.php
unchanged api/web/index.php
overwrite frontend/config/main-local.php
unchanged frontend/config/params-local.php
unchanged frontend/web/index-test.php
unchanged frontend/web/index.php
unchanged console/config/main-local.php
unchanged console/config/params-local.php
 generate cookie validation key in backend/config/main-local.php
 generate cookie validation key in frontend/config/main-local.php
  chmod 0777 backend/runtime
  chmod 0777 backend/web/assets
  chmod 0777 frontend/runtime
  chmod 0777 frontend/web/assets
  chmod 0755 yii
  chmod 0755 tests/codeception/bin/yii

... initialization completed.`
```

Comment: you can see the code of 'init' file as well for more details, its written in php. and it does pretty much what the first two answers says.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

init command just copy files from directory /environments to your project

In advanced application you have two environments by default (dev and prod), each environment have different configuration for project.

In each location you have some configuration files main.php, params.php, main-local.php, params-local.php. Files main.php and params.php are common for all environments, and files main-local.php and params-local.php are configurations for current environment.

For example you have database for real project, and database for test purpose. In this case you should write different configurations for db component in files main-local.php and params-local.php.

One more thing about this files. If you want to enable your configuration to project you should rewrite them in directory /environment. Because all *-local.php files included into git-ignore section. So you can test different configuration in /frontend/config/main-local.php file and if you succes with it you can add it to /envinronment/prod/frontend/main-local.php

Answer (score 4):

1) Generate config files for all the apps. Backend is an app and frontend is anohter app. With *main* and *main-local* you could have different settings in your local and your server for example. Common is for needs for both apps (user model, or a third-party used in both apps, ....).

> The template includes three tiers: front end, back end, and console,
>   each of which is a separate Yii application.

**From Advanced template installation guide**: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced/blob/master/docs/guide/README.md

2) Also adds permissions for the folders of each app. Example:

```
'backend/runtime',
'backend/web/assets',
'frontend/runtime',
'frontend/web/assets',
```

Check the differences between basic and advanced templates here: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced/blob/master/docs/guide/start-comparison.md