# Yii2 advanced prepare to production

Tags: deployment, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, production-environment, dev-to-production

I have an app in yii2 builded on top the template advanced, but i have a few concerns about how to deploy this app in Production.

Should i run `php init` again and set production env?

many thanks,[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GvNvS.png)

Comment: [What does ´php init´ command actually do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36791824/yii2-php-init-command)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you prepared your `Production` environment correctly - yes, you should.

Comment: I mean, can i run again the script `init` which i previously run and setting `development` for hosting deploy?